# How to perform Entity Splitting with join table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following sample data model: **Patient**, **Address** and join table **PatientDetail**. Is there a way to perform entity splitting with this model? This model is needed because a patient can have multiple addresses. In addition, I have other tables that utilize the **Address** table.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by entity splitting in your case? Entity splitting means that there will be an entity which will be mapped to more than one table (but all tables forming the entity will be in one-to-one relationship).

Comment: This is a many-to-many association. If multiple patients can share the same address, probably `IsPrimary` should be a property of `PatientDetail`.

Comment: Yes, EntitySplitting would work if its a one-to-one relationship but my problems is my patient can have many addresses and then I have other entities that use the address table as well, such as physicians and insurance companies so I was hoping to find a way that when I call save on the patient it would update the Address table and also the PatientDetail table.